# How is memory arranged in stack, heap?

Tags: c, malloc, padding, heap-memory, stack-memory

Below is the sample program i wrote to examine the memory allignements.

```
Pavan@Pavan-pc:~/working_dir/pavan/C$ cat mem3.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    /* This is generated by a template program */

    typedef struct stru_s{
        char str1[4], str2[4], str3[4];
    }stru_t;
    int main(){
        stru_t st;

        char str1[4], str2[4], str3[4];

        char *mstr1, *mstr2, *mstr3, *mstr4, *mstr5;;

        mstr1= (char*)malloc(4);
        mstr2= (char*)malloc(4);
        mstr3= (char*)malloc(4);
        mstr4= (char*)malloc(8);
        mstr5= (char*)malloc(16);

        strcpy(str1, "aaa");
        strcpy(str2, "bbb");
        strcpy(str3, "ccc");
        strcpy(mstr1, "xxx");
        strcpy(mstr2, "yyy");
        strcpy(mstr3, "zzz");

    return 0;
    }
```

Below is the examining of the memory using gdb.

```
Pavan@Pavan-pc:~/working_dir/pavan/C$ gdb mem3
    GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-60.el6_4.1)
    Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
    and "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
    For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
    Reading symbols from /home/xkumapu/working_dir/pavan/C/mem3...done.
    (gdb) b 1
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005f0: file mem3.c, line 1.
    (gdb) r
    Starting program: /home/xkumapu/working_dir/pavan/C/mem3
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

    Breakpoint 1, main () at mem3.c:17
    17          mstr1= (char*)malloc(4);
    Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.192.el6.x86_64
    (gdb) n
    18          mstr2= (char*)malloc(4);
    (gdb) n
    19          mstr3= (char*)malloc(4);
    (gdb) n
    20          mstr4= (char*)malloc(8);
    (gdb) n
    21          mstr5= (char*)malloc(16);
    (gdb) n
    23          strcpy(str1, "aaa");
    (gdb) n
    24          strcpy(str2, "bbb");
    (gdb)
    25          strcpy(str3, "ccc");
    (gdb)
    26          strcpy(mstr1, "xxx");
    (gdb)
    27          strcpy(mstr2, "yyy");
    (gdb)
    28          strcpy(mstr3, "zzz");
    (gdb)
    30      return 0;
    (gdb)
    31      }
    (gdb) x str1
    0x7fffffffe330: 0x00616161
    (gdb) x str2
    0x7fffffffe320: 0x00626262
    (gdb) x str3
    0x7fffffffe310: 0x00636363
    (gdb) x &str3
    0x7fffffffe310: 0x00636363
    (gdb) x &str2
    0x7fffffffe320: 0x00626262
    (gdb) x &str1
    0x7fffffffe330: 0x00616161  <- Aligned to 16 bytes. (from 320 to 330)
    (gdb) x &mstr1
    0x7fffffffe358: 0x00601060
    (gdb) x &mstr2
    0x7fffffffe360: 0x006010a0
    (gdb) x &mstr3
    0x7fffffffe368: 0x006010e0  <- aligned to 40 bytes. (from 0a0 to 0e0)
    (gdb) x &st.str
    There is no member named str.
    (gdb) x &st.str3
    0x7fffffffe348: 0x00400735
    (gdb) x &st.str2
    0x7fffffffe344: 0x00007fff
    (gdb) x &st.str1
    0x7fffffffe340: 0xffffe478  <- Aligned to just 4 bytes.(from 340 to 344)
    (gdb) q
    A debugging session is active.

            Inferior 1 [process 12541] will be killed.

    Quit anyway? (y or n) y
```

Can someone explain me why it took different types of alignments in structures!! And is it MCB that used memory in heap!?

Comment: What do you mean by "MCB"?

Comment: @kalaracey Memory control block. A structure that will be appended before each dynamically allocated chunk of memory. This structure contains if two values {is_available, size}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC uses a default stack alignment of 16 bytes (See the `-mpreferred-stack-boundary` option) This is why your pointer variables (which are on the stack) are aligned to 16 bytes.

The variable `st` is a structure and will be packed according to what the compiler thinks is most efficient but generally bytes will pack without padding. You have put 4 arrays of 4 bytes in your structure, so no padding is needed. Therefore each entry is 4-byte 'aligned'. Note that `st` itself still starts on a 16-byte boundary, even though its elements do not.

(If you have a mix of types in your structure, the compiler will pad them to ensure word alignment, although you can use an attribute to turn off padding if you have a good reason  - e.g. defining some kind of comms stack)

The way memory is allocated on the heap (i.e. by `malloc`) is a function of the heap allocation strategy of the system (the c library and the OS) - it's possible to use different allocation strategies but this is a big topic (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure) )

Answer (score 0):

The 0x00616161 in str1 is not an address at all, it is simply the contents of that string, which is "aaa". Note that the ascii value of 'a' is 0x61. So your statement that this is 17-byte aligned is just an incorrect interpretation of the data.

The strings allocated using malloc have some extra space because for each allocation because malloc needs some space for its own housekeeping, ie, metadata.

Finally, your stack variable(s) are just simply uninitialized and so you're looking at garbage.

Comment: Rob, Thanks for your kindly interest in helping me. Also, thanks for pointing out the typo of 17 for 16. (I changed it).

The main question of mine, is why it took 
16bytes in stack--> Major question.
4 bytes in structure -> Expected.
40 Bytes -> May be due to memory control blocks. Need explanation.

Wish you think if you can help me with those..

Comment: Looks like somebody else provided a good explanation. What you're doing is good: use the debugger to dig into things and try to understand what you are seeing, then ask questions if you need to.